# finding central tendency

Tags: mean, descriptive-statistics, median, mode, central-tendency

The following table presents frequency distribution of teachers of 1 year:

**Rank** ----------**Frequency**

Professor ------------7

Assoc Professor ------4

Asst Professor--------3

Instructor -----------5

Others ---------------3

1)find mean, median and mode.

2)which is better measure of Central tendency: mean or median or mode ?Explain with reason.

Mode will be Professor because its frequency is Max.

I have observed that the data are Ordinals so, Median would be best measure of central tendency. But What would would be the value of Median.I tried to obtain the median it is Mean of 11th term and 12th term .The 11th term is Assoc Professor and 12th term is Asst Professor.I got struck here to obtain the Median .I struck here because how I will determine the average of 2 categorical data.

Secondly, The mean would be 1 because sum of observations and number of observation both are same which is 1.Am I correct?

Comment: This has the look of a homework question. Please add the [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study) tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then explain what progress you've made so for and where you are stuck.

Comment: It might be worth revisiting the issue of data type, because Rank is not completely ordinal: "Others" could be anything from part-time adjunct graduate students through Nobel Prize visitors, distinguished professors emerita, and anything in between.  What you ought to consider first is what are the data.  They appear to be *counts,* which is a data type in its own right that often can be considered interval or ratio in nature.

Comment: Mean can not be determined because the data are of categorical nature